# Vector2 velocity not working in Unity 2018.1

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, scripting

I'm making an android game and whole of my movement mechanics are working fine except the `jump()`.

My script:

**VHandler.cs**

```
public class VJHandler : MonoBehaviour,IDragHandler, IPointerUpHandler, IPointerDownHandler {

    private Image jsContainer;
    private Image joystick;

    public Vector3 InputDirection ;

    void Start(){

        jsContainer = GetComponent<Image>();
        joystick = transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>(); //this command is used because there is only one child in hierarchy
        InputDirection = Vector3.zero;
    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData ped){
        Vector2 position = Vector2.zero;

        //To get InputDirection
        RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle
                (jsContainer.rectTransform, 
                ped.position,
                ped.pressEventCamera,
                out position);

            position.x = (position.x/jsContainer.rectTransform.sizeDelta.x);
            position.y = (position.y/jsContainer.rectTransform.sizeDelta.y);

            float x = (jsContainer.rectTransform.pivot.x == 1f) ? position.x *2 + 1 : position.x *2 - 1;
            float y = (jsContainer.rectTransform.pivot.y == 1f) ? position.y *2 + 1 : position.y *2 - 1;

            InputDirection = new Vector3 (x,y,0);
            InputDirection = (InputDirection.magnitude > 1) ? InputDirection.normalized : InputDirection;

            //to define the area in which joystick can move around
            joystick.rectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector3 (InputDirection.x * (jsContainer.rectTransform.sizeDelta.x/3)
                                                                   ,InputDirection.y * (jsContainer.rectTransform.sizeDelta.y)/3);

    }

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData ped){

        OnDrag(ped);
    }

    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData ped){

        InputDirection = Vector3.zero;
        joystick.rectTransform.anchoredPosition = Vector3.zero;
        }
    }
```

**MovePlayers.cs**

```
public class MovePlayers : MonoBehaviour
{

public float moveSpeed = 05f;
public float jumpForce = 3f;
public VJHandler jsMovement;
public bool isGrounded = false;
public Vector3 direction;

[SerializeField]
private float xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax;
private Rigidbody2D rb;

void Update()
{

    direction = jsMovement.InputDirection; //InputDirection can be used as per the need of your project
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(direction.x * moveSpeed, 0.0f);


}

void Start()
{

    //Initialization of boundaries
    xMax = Screen.width - 50; // I used 50 because the size of player is 100*100
    xMin = 50;
    yMax = Screen.height - 50;
    yMin = 50;
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if(collision.CompareTag("Ground"))
    {
        isGrounded = true;
    }
}
private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if(collision.CompareTag("Ground"))
    {
        isGrounded = false;
        }
    }
}
```

**GameManager.cs**

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {

public Rigidbody2D player;

[SerializeField]
private MovePlayers movePlayers;

void Awake()
{
    movePlayers = player.GetComponent<MovePlayers>();
}

public void Jump()
{
    if(movePlayers.isGrounded)
    {
        Debug.Log("Jumping!");
        player.velocity = new Vector2(movePlayers.direction.x, movePlayers.jumpForce);
        }
    }
}
```

These are my scripts. I added a `debug.log` to check if the button is working or not and ironically it was working fine so I believe something is
wrong with the `Vector2()`. I use Unity Remote so first I guessed it to be mobile only problem but it happens in PC as well. I don't know what's wrong, I even tried to change the `jumpFore o 300f` but no luck. `Physics.gravity` is set to 10(Estimated real gravity 9.8).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should MovePlayers.cs not be:

```
void Update()
{
    direction = jsMovement.InputDirection; //InputDirection can be used as per the need of your project
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(direction.x * moveSpeed, direction.y * moveSpeed);
}
```

or even, simply `rb.velocity = direction * moveSpeed;` ?

Another point that might be incorrect, is the `GameManager` is modifying the player `RigidBody`, and so is your `MovePlayers` class as well. Your RigidBody.velocity is being modified twice, with possibly conflicting values.